# Trigger Validation on QuoteLineItem Based on Quote Status

Tags: trigger, quote, delete, before-trigger, quotelineitem

I've made a research, try a few things...but I don't really see a good example where to understand how to do this.

I want an error messaget to be shown when I try to update or delete a QuoteLineItem from the Related List within the Quote detail page.

In a "before insert" and "before delete" trigger for the QuoteLineItem object I would like to access to the Status field from the Quote parent object and if the Status is "Approved" interrupt the insert/delete process.

I've come to this piece of code:

```
    trigger blockDelete on QuoteLineItem(before delete, before update) {

    QuoteLineItem myVar = [SELECT Quote.Id, Quote.Status from QuoteLineItem where Id IN: trigger.old];

    if (Trigger.isUpdate){
        for (QuoteLineItem q : Trigger.old){
                if(myVar.Quote.Status == 'Aprobado') {
                    // Adding the error to the new object
                    Trigger.newMap.get(q.Id).addError('Quote approved  --> QuoteLineItem can not be modified');
                }
            } 
    } else {
        for (QuoteLineItem q : Trigger.old){
                if(myVar.Quote.Status == 'Aprobado') {
                    // Adding the error to the new object
                    myVar.Quote.Id.addError('Quote approved  --> QuoteLineItem can not be deleted');
                }
            } 
    }
```

}

But I'm still not able to make it work completely...

**UPDATE**

I've accomplish to avoid the edition of a QuoteLineItem by **using a Validation Rule** like suggested in on of the answers:

```
             ISPICKVAL(Quote.Status, 'Approved')
```

But this isn't working when it comes to avoid deletion.

So, I've also tried **with a trigger** (I've updated the code based on other answer) and it also works fine for avoiding the edition but for the deletion doesn't work neither. It redirects me to a error page:

> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the
>   affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex
>   trigger blockDelete caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: blockDelete: execution of BeforeDelete caused by:
>   System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors:
>   Trigger.blockDelete: line 16, column 1".

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are not seeing the error is because the [addError](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_SObject_field_addError.htm) needs to be on one of the `QuoteLineItem` records from the trigger context, which are the records that the save is been done on.

See below for a working example.

```
trigger myAccountTrigger on QuoteLineItem(before delete, before update) {
    for (QuoteLineItem q : Trigger.old){
        if(q.Status == 'Approved') {
            // Adding the error to the new object
            Trigger.newMap.get(q.Id).addError("Quote approved  --> QuoteLineItem's can't be modified");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. `trigger.newMap` is null `before delete`.

Comment: Good solution for the `before update`. But, @AdrianLarson you were also right, for the delete was necessary to use `trigger.oldMap`, but still not working as expected. See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just a `Validation Rule` on `QuoteLineItem`. Your only criterion would be:

```
ISPICKVAL(Quote.Status, 'Approved')
```

You can then have just call the below from your delete trigger:

```
public static void validateDeletion(List<QuoteLineItem> lineItems)
{
    Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (QuoteLineItem lineItem : lineItems)
        quoteIds.add(lineItem.QuoteId);
    Map<Id, Quote> quotes = new Map<Id, Quote>([
        SELECT Status FROM Quote WHERE Id IN :quoteIds
    ]);

    for (QuoteLineItem lineItem : lineItems) {
        if(Quotes.get(lineItem.QuoteId).Status == 'Approved') {
            lineItem.addError('message');
        }
    }
}
```

like so:

```
trigger myAccountTrigger on QuoteLineItem(before delete) {
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isDelete)
        {
            QuoteLineItemServices.validateDeletion(trigger.old);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you mention that the process is "kind of backwards". My intention is to show the error message when you try to update or delete a QuoteLineItem from the RelatedList within the Quote detail page. In case that changes anything.

Comment: I understand your intention, you were adding the error to `Quote` in your code. Just use a validation rule on `QuoteLineItem`. You don't need a trigger at all for this validation.

Comment: It works fine with the update of a  QuoteLineItem, but it isn't working for the deleting. If I click "Delete" on  a QuoteLineItem in the Realted List, it is deleted.